# Reading value of Observable variable without rerunning assigned function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular7

I've currently got a function in my angular component that is run whenever I want to upload a list of files.

I want to both follow the upload progress to then empty the list of files and to track the progress of the upload for a progress bar.

My current problem is that when I request the value of `uploadProgress` it reruns `this.pictureService.upload(this.selectedFiles)` and it uploads the files twice.

My function currently looks like this:

```
uploadImages() {
  // Upload picture and save progress to observable
  const uploadProgress: Observable<HttpEvent<HttpUploadProgressEvent>> = this.pictureService.upload(this.selectedFiles);

  // Create snackbar with observable for progress bar
  this.snackBar.openFromComponent(UploadProgressComponent, {
    data: { uploadProgress },
  });

  // Wait for uploading to be finished and then clear selected files and preview URLs
  uploadProgress.subscribe((event: HttpUploadProgressEvent) => {
    if (event.loaded === event.total && event.loaded !== undefined) {
      this.selectedFiles = null;
      this.previewUrls = [];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You can call `uploadImages()` once and then use `share()` operator that will hold a single subscription.

Comment: FYI 8.1 exposes the HttpUploadProgressEvent interface as public API. It may be easier to work with now: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpUploadProgressEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin suggested, I added `.pipe(share())` at the end of my constant and it now works as intended.

My code now looks like this:

```
uploadImages() {
  // Upload picture and save progress to observable
  const uploadProgress = this.pictureService.upload(this.selectedFiles).pipe(share());

  // Create snackbar with observable for progress bar
  this.snackBar.openFromComponent(UploadProgressComponent, {
    data: { uploadProgress },
  });

  // Wait for uploading to be finished and then clear selected files and preview URLs
  uploadProgress.subscribe((event: HttpUploadProgressEvent) => {
    if (event.loaded === event.total && event.loaded !== undefined) {
      this.selectedFiles = null;
      this.previewUrls = [];
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

everytime you call .subscribe the observable gets called (see [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/294). )

If you are doing that in the openFromComponent function consider not calling .subscribe a second time but something like this:

```
uploadImages() {
// Upload picture and save progress to observable
const uploadProgress: Observable<HttpEvent<HttpUploadProgressEvent>> = this.pictureService.upload(this.selectedFiles);

// Create snackbar with observable for progress bar
this.snackBar.openFromComponent(UploadProgressComponent, {
  data: {
    uploadProgress.pipe(tap((event: HttpUploadProgressEvent) => {
      if (event.loaded === event.total && event.loaded !== undefined) {
        this.selectedFiles = null;
        this.previewUrls = [];
      }
    }))
  }
})
```

}